# How to upgrade ipython from 0.12 to 0.13?

Tags: ipython

I am using the latest free version of Enthought package on Mac lion OS. The ipython comes with the package is 0.12. How can I upgrade it to 0.13?

When I follow the instruction and run the following command

```
sudo easy_install ipython[zmq,qtconsole,notebook,test]
```

I got following errors:

```
Searching for ipython[zmq,qtconsole,notebook,test]
Best match: ipython 0.12.1
Adding ipython 0.12.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Processing dependencies for ipython[zmq,qtconsole,notebook,test]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/easy_install", line 10, in 
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1915, in main
    with_ei_usage(lambda:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1896, in with_ei_usage
    return f()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1919, in 
    distclass=DistributionWithoutHelpCommands, **kw
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 350, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 587, in easy_install
    self.process_distribution(spec, dist, deps, "Using")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 674, in process_distribution
    [requirement], self.local_index, self.easy_install
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 593, in resolve
    requirements.extend(dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2219, in requires
    "%s has no such extra feature %r" % (self, ext)
pkg_resources.UnknownExtra: ipython 0.12.1 has no such extra feature 'zmq'
```

It looks it does not search for 0.13. It is still looking for 0.12.

How can I upgrade to 0.13?

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me on Snow Leopard with EPD 7.3:

```
sudo easy_install -U ipython
```

Answer (score 9):

for ubuntu users, please follow this step.

```
pip install ipython --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) updating my user level ie `pip install --user ipython` installation via

```
$ which ipython
# /home/username/.local/bin/ipython
$ pip install --user -U ipython
```